# What is SOL_ used for?

Tags: python, c, sockets

Reading Python library and came across this:

```
socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, proto=socket.SOL_TCP)
```

I understand it's specifying that TCP is to be used but what is the significance of `SOL_`? After some searching I've found that it's part of the C library, understandable, but can't seem to find any specific explanation of it.

I did read that it had to do with layers, perhaps "SOcket Layer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed stands  for *"socket layer"* or *"socket options layer"* in the original [BSD socket API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), so Python keeps the naming for consistency.